# Adding a UNION to two SELECT statements (using CASE)

Tags: sql, union

OK here is my actual tables and data:

This is just returning Y or N and not comparing the data directly

tblViewLearners  (this intID = intLearnerID in the other table)

```
IntID   -   FirstName    -  Surname   -  Course    - Dob    - address     - nationality
701271      Julie           Barnett      Physics     NULL       NULL          NULL
345239      Rachel          Smith        Physics     NULL       NULL          NULL
240259      David           Feffer       Maths       NULL       NULL          NULL
```

tblAWARDSLearner  (basically if the learner made it to this table that have a 'DISTINCTION')

```
 intID   -  intLearnerID    -  dateawarded
 2402       701271             21/04/1992
 1032       345239             01/01/2010
```

MY GOAL

```
IntID   -   FirstName    -  Surname   -  Course     - DISTINCTION Awarded
701271      Julie           Barnett      Physics          Yes
345239      Rachel          Smith        Physics          Yes
240259      David           Feffer       Maths            No
```

THE CODE

```
SELECT Y.intID
FROM
(
SELECT    A.* ,   
CASE 
        WHEN B.intLearnerID IS NULL THEN 'N' 
        ELSE 'Y' 
END 'DISTINCTION Awarded' x
FROM 
    tblviewlearners A
    LEFT JOIN tblAWARDSLearner B
    ON A.intID = B.intLearnerID

)AS Y;
```

I also with to join it with another table but will cross that bridge once the above is working, its worth noting that the above tables have already been declared further up so when I do join I don't need to include it in a FROM and just compare the table columns more directly (I think this is correct).   However I want to get the above working first.

Comment: the brackets aren't matched? Also, `'BestSeller'` is a string not an identifier. Not knowing your RDBMS I can't tell you how to fix that ;)

Comment: what's the `'BestSeller'` doing after the `END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit #2, based on your update, using your sample data you should be able use the following:

```
SELECT  A.Intid, A.Firstname, A.Surname, A.Course,   
  CASE 
        WHEN B.intLearnerID IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
  END DISTINCTIONAwarded 
FROM tblviewlearners A
LEFT JOIN tblAWARDSLearner B
  ON A.intID = B.intLearnerID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/491a0/6)

This gives you the result that you want:

```
|  INTID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME |  COURSE | DISTINCTIONAWARDED |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 701271 |     Julie | Barnett | Physics |                Yes |
| 345239 |    Rachel |   Smith | Physics |                Yes |
| 240259 |     David |  Feffer |   Maths |                 No |
```

<strike>You have several issues with your current query. First, you have an extra closing parentheses `)` at the end after the final `JOIN` - remove it. Second, you are giving the `BestSeller` a string column name, you cannot use string literals - remove the single quotes. Finally in your second query you are using `SELECT A.*` but the `A` alias is from the inner query you need to use the alias `Y`:</strike>

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblbookshop 
INNER JOIN tblAllsellers
    ON tblbookshop.productID = tblAllsellers.BookID
UNION
SELECT Y.*  
FROM AnotherTable X 
JOIN 
 (
    SELECT  A.*, 
        CASE 
            WHEN B.ProductId IS NULL THEN 'N' 
            ELSE 'Y' 
        END BestSeller
    FROM tblAllSellers A
    LEFT JOIN tblBestSellers B
        ON A.ProductId = B.ProductID
 ) AS Y
    ON X.ProductId = Y.ProductID
```

*Note, when you are using a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` the number of columns needs to be the same in both queries and the data types need to be the same with the columns in both queries.*

Edit, based on your comment that you are getting an error with the `UNION`, I have a few suggestions. While I cannot see your full table structure if you have a different number of columns, then you might be able to include a placeholder column in the query that has the fewer number of columns. Here is an example these sample tables have s different number of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1([col1] int, [col2] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO Table1 ([col1], [col2])
VALUES (1, 'test'),(2, 'blah');

CREATE TABLE Table2 ([col1] int, [col2] varchar(5), [col3] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO Table2 ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES  (1, 'test1', 'data1'),  (2, 'test2', 'data2');
```

If I attempt a `UNION` operation then it will generate an error message, but if I include a placeholder column, then it will work:

```
select col1, col2, null as col3
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3
from table2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fe6a/1)

My other suggestion to you would be to not use the `SELECT *` on your tables, then you can specify what columns you want to return and this can correct the error that you are receiving.

Comment: hmmm I am getting the following error: Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I have discovered that both tables have a matching column but not exactly the same amount of columns so I used INTERSECT instead but am still getting the following error message?

Comment: @starydynamo the number of columns **must** be the same in order for a `UNION` operation. If you do not have the same number of columns, then you can use a placeholder column. For example, if your first query has one less column, then place a null value where the other column is on the second query.

Comment: @starydynamo see my edit with some suggestions on how to fix the error.  If you want, then create a sql fiddle with your tables and some data and I can take a better look.

Comment: It just dawned on me that because of the UNION, do I have to the same amount of columns with the all the tables before the join also?  As the error is the same and is flagging LINE 1.  This would be highly problematical as it would mean I would need to have approx 30 columns as NULL (as shown above.)

Comment: @starydynamo please see my edit, you can use the above query as the starting point for your solution.

Comment: Thanks so much blufeet for the answers and all the work towards it I know you went above and beyond on this.  Is there a way I private msg you to thank you personally?

Comment: @starydynamo happy to help, your acceptance/upvote of this answer is thanks enough. :)

Comment: @starydynamo accept is only half of the battle. click the "up arrow" too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove that last ")".

I suggest you to enclose BOTH Select within ( ) so you get

```
(SELECT * 
FROM tblbookshop INNERJOIN tblAllsellers
ON tblbookshop.productID = tblAllsellers.BookID)

UNION
( SELECT A.*  
 FROM 
 AnotherTable X 
 JOIN 
 (
    SELECT 
        A.*, 
        CASE 
            WHEN B.ProductId IS NULL THEN 'N' 
            ELSE 'Y' 
        END 'BestSeller'
    FROM 
        tblAllSellers A
        LEFT JOIN tblBestSellers B
        ON A.ProductId = B.ProductID
 ) AS Y
 ON X.ProductId = Y.ProductID)
```